# Get 403 Forbidden when downloading indigo packages from package.ros.org

Tags: ros, server, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I got error '403 Forbidden' messages when I use '$ apt-get install' to install most indigo packages, when I visit the website `http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r` directly, I found that I get 403 forbidden only when I try to download indigo packages, packages for kinetic or jade or other distro are totally accessible.

I wonder if it is a server error or it's just my Internet doesn't works fine(I'm in China, BTW), I don't think I would blame it on the system's settings since I can't download those packages form Windows System, either. Error messages are listed below, Help me please!

Error Messages:

```
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-convex-decomposition amd64 0.1.10-0trusty-20160321-180351-0700
  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-convex-decomposition/ros-indigo-convex-decomposition_0.1.10-0trusty-20160321-180351-0700_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268625/get-403-forbidden-when-downloading-indigo-packages-from-package.ros.org/) by [Luk Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31558/luk-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll try to find an earlier Q&A that I've seen about a similar question, but for now: it could well be that there is a proxy or firewall between you and `packages.ros.org` that is interfering with your network traffic. We've seen that before.

What you could perhaps try is to see whether any of the mirrors in China do work. See [wiki/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors) for the global list of mirrors.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luk Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31558/luk-wang/) on 2017-08-12**:
Thanks for quick reply! I managed to download the packages after I update the source.list! I have actually tried that in Software & Updates before, seems that not every mirror works properly, but I do have solved the problem this time! Thanks again!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-12**:
If there really is a problem with one of the mirrors, you should tell us. Perhaps something can be done about it.

But as I wrote earlier, we've seen instances where proxies and / or firewalls interfere with network traffic, resulting in the sort of strange problems that you report.